# Embedded video with specified start time won't restart at that time on refresh

Tags: html, youtube, video-embedding

I'm trying to get an embedded video to start and end at a specific time. But, I need it to start and end at the specified times even when the video is refreshed. However, while I can get the start and end times to work on the first viewing, when the video is refreshed, it starts from the beginning.

I have no idea how to fix this, or whether it is possible, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Here is my code:

```
<iframe 
    width="560" 
    height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DAOZJPquY_w?start=10&end=15&amp;" 
    title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: You mean, when the page refreshes? Or do you mean, when the video has finished and then is played again?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I should have clarified...I mean when the video finishes, and the user refreshes the video to listen to it a second and maybe 3rd time.